# Delete textarea text on submit in new tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, chat

So I'm working on a chat system and even though I know it works in a pretty lame way - submitting messages in a new window () - I'm interested if there's any way to reset the textarea's content after sending the message.

Now, the problem is, I've even actually found ways to do so via JavaScript (editing the textarea's value), but I don't know how to "launch" the javascript after submitting the form.

Obviously, I can just use onSubmit(), but that delete's the value BEFORE sending the data. So it works, but sends an empty text.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: The code is so messy I don't think it makes a lot of sense. I only need help with this certain problem, any ideas? Though if it is really needed, I can post some snippets. Just tell me what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I've used a JavaScript timer to run the clearing function 300 ms after clicking the submit button. Works. Thanks all :)

Answer (score 1):

A common solution is to copy the values of your `<form>` into an object which you can then convert to JSON. That way, you have a copy of the values which doesn't change when you reset the fields of the form. [jQuery will make this very simple.](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) See also: [serializing and submitting a form with jQuery POST and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173965/serializing-and-submitting-a-form-with-jquery-post-and-php)

The second solution is to submit the form and as the last thing, add a timeout which resets the form. But there will be a small gap and a user might be able to type while your handler is clearing the form.