# Post php form jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have form with input field generated from loop, ie

```
<form name="" method='post' action=''>
<?php
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
 echo "<input type='text' name='data[]' class='data_cls' value='".$i."'>";
}
?>
<input type='submit' id='btn' value='save'>
```

i want to submit the form using jquery ajax.

```
$('.btn').click(function(){

            var datString = "HOW TO GET THESE VALUES";

            $.ajax({
            url: "data_process.php",
            type: "post",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data) {
                alert('OK');
            }
        }); 

    });
```

Comment: Use `serialize()`. Then in your `$.ajax` call: `data: $('form').serialize();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [serializing and submitting a form with jQuery POST and php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173965/serializing-and-submitting-a-form-with-jquery-post-and-php)

Comment: The best way to do this really depends on what your desired result is.

Comment: @Jasiralwafaa  check ma ans, i have also added how you could receive the data on the PHP page. Hope the solutions would help

Answer (score 3):

You can use [.serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) jQuery method to get the form data. Like this,

```
$('.btn').click(function(){

            var dataString = $('#FORM_ID').serialize();
            //replace FORM_ID with the ID of the form.

            $.ajax({
            url: "data_process.php",
            type: "post",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data) {
                alert('OK');
            }
        }); 

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var datString = "";

$(".data_cls")
        .map(function () {
            datString += $(this).val();
        })
        .get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var Data = {};
$('input[name=data]').each(function(i) {
  Data[i] = $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgot to bind parameter in data ajax post

```
$('.btn').click(function(){

            var datString = "'HOW TO GET THESE VALUES'";

            $.ajax({
            url: "data_process.php",
            type: "post",
            data: "'USERPARAMETR' : " dataString,
            success: function(data) {
                alert('OK');
            }
        }); 

    });
```

If you not use parameter in data_process.php page. Please use it.

Please update and check

Answer (score 0):

First give the form an ID or class i.e. form

```
<form name="" method='post' action='' id='form'>...
```

Then you may capture all inputs from the from using the general serialize method

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click", ".btn", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var datastring = $("#form").serialize();

{
        $.ajax({
        url: "data_process.php",
        type: "post",
        data: dataString,
...
```

And on the PHP page you will receive the data as posted

```
$values = $_POST['data'];

$N = count($values);

for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
{

   $currentvalue = $values[$i];
   //now this value will loop and you will do with it the way you want to
   //For example
   $save =  mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE table SET `column` = '$currentvalue' WHERE ...") or die(mysqli_error($link));

}
```