# JSON to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm creating a login form with html,css and javascript.

I'm doing a POST to an API in order to receive some JSON with the identified username that I just submitted in the form.

If the email and password are correct, I receive the JSON with all the info from my API. The problem is that I don't know how to manipulate the info that I receive... I'd like to save the JSON I'm receiving through the POST to a variable and then be able to access the account type or the other properties of that object.

```
<form name="login" id="myForm" action="API_URL" method="post" class="form-signin">
    <h3 class="form-signin-heading">Por favor inicie sesión</h3>
    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">E-mail</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" required autofocus>
    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Recordarme
      </label>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" id type="submit">Iniciar sesión</button>
  </form>
```

After hitting submit, I receive the JSON like this:
!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wM6aQ.jpg)
This is my JQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js%22%3E



$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#myform').submit(function() {

              $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: '/form/',
                  data: {
                      email: $("#inputEmail").val(),
                      password: $("#inputPassword").val()
                  },
                  success: function(data)
                  {
                      if (data === 'Correct') {

                        var objeto = data.parse();
                        console.log(objeto);

                      }
                      else {
                          alert(data);
                      }
                  }
              });
      });
  });

  </script>
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is the hard part of searching for [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)?

Comment: I am unable to view your JSON Screenshot you attached.. can you post it again

Comment: share the JS code for form submission part

Comment: refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255344/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-post-json-data

Comment: Here's more reference - https://www.abeautifulsite.net/postjson-for-jquery

Comment: Serialize & submit form - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173965/serializing-and-submitting-a-form-with-jquery-post-and-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use JQuery to post JSON data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255344/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-post-json-data)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Javascript try like this:

```
              $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/form/',
                data: {
                   email: $("#inputEmail").val(),
                   password: $("#inputPassword").val()
                },
                success: function(response){
                    var data = response;
                    contactData = JSON.parse(data);
                        console.log("ID: " + contactData.id);
                        console.log("ID: " + contactData.user_type_id);
                        console.log("ID: " + contactData.first_name);
                        console.log("ID: " + contactData.last_name);
                        console.log("ID: " + contactData.email);
                        console.log("ID: " + contactData.password);

                 },
                failure : function(data){
                    alert('Server Connection failed');
                },
                error : function(request,error){
                    alert(error);
                }
             });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get Json in array in php with
`mixed json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )`

Comment: but he doesn't mention that he's using PHP

Comment: For example. He can edit it with his own language. Just a search on this item is said

Answer (score 0):

You are posting data and it will be received in string format.If you are only dealing with JSON then you can use JSON parser like this

```
let body = JSON.Parse(req.body);
```

Now body variable will contain an object and you can access properties easily.If you are using nodeJs on server side than body-parser middle ware can be used also.Let me know in comment if there is something contrary.

Answer (score -1):

You need to invoke the call using JavaScript & AJAX.

1. Add an OnClick event listener to the submit button and call `handleLoginClicked()`.
2. Collect all variable from the inputs and use ajax to post to the url.
3. Get back the response and parse the JSON, assign to a javascript variable.

You can use jQuery for example to do so: [jQuery.Post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)