# Sending data of input text and hidden field to controller name dosavenews in spring jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I need to send the data of input text to my controller with other data, I don't know how to get the text from input text and send to controller, help me

```
<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Save news</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

        <%
            String link = request.getParameter("link");
         %>

        <input type="text" placeholder="Please enter news heading" name="NewsName" id="a1"/>
        <input type="hidden" value="<%=link %>" name="link"/>
        <input type="hidden" value="1" name="id"/>
        <label><%=link %></label>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <form method="post" action="doSaveNews?NewsName1=<%=NewsName %>">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

error:

NewsName cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: Please put the input tags inside form tag or broader the scope of the form tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="doSaveNews?NewsName1=<%=NewsName %>">
```

**<%=NewsName %>**

you are trying to submit the url using a variable called "NewsName" it is supposed to be a Java object because it is inside the scriptlet tag.

What you need to do is.

- Get the value of the input element in javascript.
- Write a "onSubmit"
  method in javascript, serialize the form & then form your url in
  javascript, submit the form.

This link might help [serializing and submitting a form with jQuery POST and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173965/serializing-and-submitting-a-form-with-jquery-post-and-php)