# How to open an ajax in new tab?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

If I understood correctly, then the following will send the `formData` to `test.php` silently in the background.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'test.php');
xhr.send(formData);
```

However, I would like to have the same behavior as if one submits a form with a `target="_blank"` attribute. So to open test.php with the post data in a new tab.

Comment: then don't use ajax

Comment: @slash197 Thanks. So what could I use instead? I am trying to send form data from a file input with the `multiple` attribute set but want to send each file to a new tab rather than all on one. So I thought I could grab the files and send them via ajax...

Comment: why do you want to use ajax then? the whole point of using ajax is to make the page load event invisible and make asynchronous call.

Comment: @TazbirBhuiyan Because I don't know of any other client side (javascript) method to send a file via post. Any pointers much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jQuery serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to serialize the form and then [curl the data to your PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173965/serializing-and-submitting-a-form-with-jquery-post-and-php). Make sure to disable posting the form by disabling your buttons default function, [see this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173965/serializing-and-submitting-a-form-with-jquery-post-and-php).

Comment: Thanks. However, in the jQuery serialize documentary you refer to it says explicitly that "Data from file select elements is not serialized." Not sure how this is supposed to work then.

Comment: You can try having a variable in your script to store the Blob of the file. On form validation, check to make sure that it is a valid Blob, if valid, append it to your FormData object. To get the Blob from an input element see https://gist.github.com/nolanlawson/62e747cea7af01542479