# How to remain selected value of dropdown after click on submit button

Tags: javascript, php, button

I want to show selected data after click on submit.I have search too much but not get proper answer.

[image]

i used this code but what will be the next step i am not getting this.

```
if($actiondone!=''){
    echo "<script>
        $('#actiondoc').val();
        </script>";
}
```

Please guide me for solutuion

Thanks

Comment: Is it PHP code? Please specify and tag properly the question.

Comment: That's a JQuery statement you're echoing, so are you sure you have JQuery included in your solution?  You haven't tagged your question as such.

Comment: I have solved this problem

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use PHP to interact with the user.

After the page has rendered, PHP is finished. If you want to interact with the user (i.e. detect changes to drop-downs, etc) you must use jQuery/javascript *only*.

For your example, you need to have the jQuery code pre-existing in the page - that is, the javascript gets written into the DOM as the page is being initially rendered. You can add the jQuery/javascript code as part of the HTML, or you can `echo` that code in PHP as the page is being built -- but it must be on the page when the user gets control of the DOM.

#### Working demo:

```js
$(function(){
    $('#form_submit').click(function(){
        alert( $('#actiondoc').val() );
        return false; //this line cancels the SUBMIT action of the form
    });
    
    $('#actiondoc').change(function(){
      alert('You chose: ' + $(this).find('option:selected').text() );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="your_form">
    <select id="actiondoc">
        <option value="">Choose:</option>
        <option value="chg">change of tyre</option>
        <option value="rnw">renew tyre</option>
    </select>
    <input id="form_submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

---

You say that you want to show the selected choice after user clicks on submit, but there might be a problem with that idea:

When user clicks submit, an HTML form will immediately (a) get the values of the form controls and (b) deliver them to the page specified on the `<form action="new_page.php" method="post">` -- so, in this code right here, the browser will navigate over to `new_page.php` and deliver the form values to that page.

The point is: the page will change *(unless you are using AJAX - are you?)* - so you cannot show anything more on that page because the user isn't on that page any longer.

So, you can show the value of the `#actiondoc` control on the new page, ***OR*** you can ***intercept*** the submit function, as I did in my demo above when I displayed the `alert()`

If you tell us more about *exactly* what you want to do, we can help more.

---

References:

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

[AJAX vs Form Submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293375/ajax-vs-form-submission)

[YouTube - Simple AJAX Contact Form - HTML, PHP, AJAX](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nbMXeaozgqg)

Comment: when i remove return false its not working fine ,i need submit buttton should work

Comment: i am not using ajax

Comment: In that case, the page will switch away from the webpage that the `#actiondoc` dropdown is on, over to the page specified in your `<form>` tag. Please: (1) post your HTML that includes the form tag, and (2) tell us what you want to happen when the user clicks the `submit` button. Please tell us *exactly* (everything) you want to happen, step-by-step. *Thanks!*

Comment: Note: ***If*** your form tag does not specify another page in the `action=""` attribute on the form tag, then the page will simply reload.  For example: If your form tag just looks like this: `<form>`, then when the user clicks the `submit` button inside that form, the page will just reload itself.  If that is happening, now you know why.