# Form data POST vs Ajax POST

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, python-3.x, post

I am currently developing a UI where user enters their personal information in the form and when they click submit, the data gets inserted into the database.

Now, I have two ways of sending the form data fro UI to the backend.

**1) Using the Form POST method**

**2) Using Ajax POST method**

Out of both, which one is the best to follow (or) anything is fine? are there any limitations in certain cases?

I am developing the website in Django

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AJAX vs Form Submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293375/ajax-vs-form-submission)

Comment: The question of ajax vs form submission is primarily related to if the source page needs to reload, or transition, or not as a result of the action.